# .dae and fbx export both don't export animation?

Tags: animation, export, unity, .fbx

Ok Im trying to export an animated mesh to Unity, and Ive tried fbx 7.4 and 6.1, and dae. Here are my dae settings, fbx is just the standard:

[image]

No matter which (dae gives the best result) the full animation doesn't export - just the first half. The animation is all bones scaling from 0 to 1. I have no shapekeys.

What could be the problem?

EDIT: the error I get In Unity is:

transform.localRotation assign attempt for 'Bone' is not valid. Input rotation is { NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN }.
UnityEditorInternal.InternalEditorUtility:ProjectWindowDrag(HierarchyProperty, Boolean)
UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent(Int32, IntPtr)

EDIT: now works in a viewer but in Unity I get (it is supposed to be a full tree):

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend using FBX. Try these settings, note the last section for animation is for the simplest application if your using frame ranges and not NLA tracks. Make sure you timeline 'end' includes all your keys an your not using an [alternate start/end](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/editors/timeline.html#header-controls).

[image: FBX for Unity, non NLA]

Comment: Follow up - it appears to work in an fbx viewer but not in Unity. Check my edit - any ideas?